# Convergence of geometric series of probabilities.

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory

Let $X$ be an absolutely continuous random variable with strictly positive pdf $f$ and cdf $F$. Moreover, let $\gamma\in(0,1)$. I am interested when
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(|X|<\gamma^n) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} F(\gamma^n) - F(-\gamma^n)
$$
converges. One option would be to impose that $F$ is $K$-Lipschitz continuous, since then $F(\gamma^n) - F(-\gamma^n) \le 2K\gamma^n$ and thus the series reduces to a geometric one. Is it also sufficient if $F$ is assumed to be uniformly continuous? If not, are there additional assumptions that do ensure this is enough?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uniform continuity is insufficient. Let $$F(x) = 
\begin{cases}
0&x\le -e^{-2}\\
1/2 - 1/\ln(-1/x)&-e^{-2}\le x\le 0\\
1/2 + 1/\ln(1/x)&0\le x\le e^{-2}\\
1&x\ge e^{-2}
\end{cases}$$
This is a cdf which is uniformly continuous and for which $\sum_{n}F(\gamma^n)$ does not converge for any $0<\gamma<1$.

For additional assumptions, it suffices for $F$ to be $\alpha$-Hölder continuous at zero for some $\alpha>0$. So if $F(x)=1/2+\text{sign}(x)\sqrt{|x|}$ in a neighborhood of $0$, then your sum converges, even though $F$ is not Lipschitz.